# 'i' doesn't exits in the current context for MVC page, onload jquery event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have some values in Model and onload itself want to iterate through the Model count and assign values to some textbox and dropdown controls.

For example, for one of the dropdown, i have hardcoded as below and working.

```
$('#COMBO1 option').filter(function () {                
     return (this.text == '@Model.ControlValue');
}).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Please provide solution where I can do the above for multiple dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

First assign `'@Model.ControlValue'` to a var and then use it in your code

Comment: Actually I have a Arraylist in Model and it has some values. Onload I want to loop through and assign each value to the dropdownlist.
I dont want to create another action to fetch the value or call an ajax method to bind the values. By hardcodeing, i have achieved as per code posted in question, but want to do dynamically.

Comment: in this case try to use for drop down

$("select").find("option").filter(function () {                
     return (this.text == '@Model.ControlValue');
}).attr('selected', 'selected');

and for textbox

$("input[type='text']").filter(function () {                
     return (this.text == '@Model.ControlValue');
}).attr('selected', 'selected');

Comment: ControlValue is an arraylist having 2 values. I have two dropdowns in a page and lets say no textboxes. How do I use filter function to loop through. @Model.ControlValues[i] is not working for onload binding. Please provide me the solution.

Comment: @Ansh...any alternate ways ?

Comment: Using that example, i have posted that code in the question. For multiple drodowns, I want to bind values present in Model.ControlValues[0], Model.ControlValues[1], Model.ControlValues[2] etc...Please provide some code snippets...

Comment: $("select").find("option").each(function () {
        $(this).removeAttr("selected");
    }).filter(function () {
        return ($(this).text() == '@Model.ControlValue');
    }).attr("selected", "selected");